# Loop through a list and get each value in the list

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a folder in ADLS that has few files. For the purpose of understanding, I will keep it simple. I have the following three files. When I loop through this folder, I want to get the "file name" and "source" as separate parameters so that I can pass it subsequent activities/pipelines.

> employee_crm.txt
>
> contractor_ps.txt
>
> manager_director_sap.txt

I want to put this in an array so that it can be passed accordingly to the subsequent activities.

(employee, contractor, manager_director)

(crm, ps, sap)

I want to pass two parameters to my subsequent activity (may be a stored procedure) as usp_foo (employee, crm) and it will execute the process based on the parameters. Similary, usp_foo (contractor, ps) and usp_foo (manager_director, sap).

How do I get the child items as two separate parameters so that it can be passed to SP?

Answer (score 1):

To rephrase the question, you would like to 1) get a list of blob names and 2) parse those names into 2 variables. This pattern occurs frequently, so the following steps will guide you through how to accomplish these tasks.

1. Define an ADLS DataSet that specifies the folder. You do not need a schema, and you can optionally parameterize the FileSystem and Directory names:
   [image]
2. To get a list of the objects within, use the GetMetadata activity. Expand the "Field list" section and select "Child Items" in the drop down:
   [image]
3. Add a Filter activity to make sure you are only dealing with .txt files. Note it targets the "childItems" property:

[image]

You may obviously alter these expressions to meet the specific needs of your project.

4. Use ForEach activity to loop through each element in the Filter sequentially:
   [image]

   5. Inside the ForEach, add activities to parse the filename. To access the fileName, use "item().name":
      [image]
      [image]

In my example, I am storing these values as pipeline variables, which are global [hence the need to perform this operation sequentially]. Storing them in an Array for further use gets complicated and tricky in a hurry because of the limited Array and Object support in the Pipeline Expression Language. The inability to have nested foreach activities may also be a factor.

To overcome these, at this point I would pass these values to another pipeline directly inside the ForEach loop.
[image]

This pattern has the added benefit of allowing individual file execution apart from the folder processing.

Comment: thanks for posting the detailed explanation. One question here - instead of passing it to another Pipeline, can I pass it to Stored Procedure which is expecting these two parameters?

Comment: Absolutely - I only mentioned another pipeline because you had said "subsequent activities, so I thought you had more to do with those parameters.

Comment: Thank you! Let me try that and get back to you.